# Is the converse of the Liskov principle true? if not give a counter example

Tags: type-theory

As I understand the Liskov Substitution Principle, it says that if $A\subset B$ and $X \subset Y$ then $(B\to X) \subset (A\to Y)$.  I'm having trouble understanding what the converse of this statement would mean, and whether it is true.

If $(B\to X) \subset (A\to Y)$, then $A\subset B$ and $X \subset Y$.  For a counter example, I'd need to exhibit A,B such that $A\not\subset B$ or X,Y such that $X \not\subset Y$, for which $(B\to X) \subset (A\to Y)$ still holds.  Right?

Can someone help?

Comment: Yes, I think you have it right. I think that the answer is going to be related to the specific type theory or programming language that you are working in.

Comment: If you don't get useful answers here in a couple days, it may help to post on a more CS-oriented StackExchange site.  If you do so, it may help to include more information about the setting you are working in and where you were coming from when you encountered this problem.